# Banner Ads in React Native 2018?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, admob

I'm just wondering if it's still possible to implement banner ads in a React Native App. I've tried using some but they don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by banner ads? Build them yourself in React Native? Use an SDK from an ad network?

Comment: Banner ads that you can get from Google Admob

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to display banner ads in React Native. I recommend two popular libraries which help you do that.

- The first one is [react-native-admob](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob)
- The second one is [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) which is provided so many libraries to help you use firebase services (included admob). I prefer this one.

PS: The integrating is a little bit complicated but keep patient then they work like charm.

Cheer!

---

Comment: Is there any way to check Number of download from Banner event?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve done some digging on this. And here is what I've found so far.

**AdMob: Supported and verified**
I managed to make this work. In terms of dependency, AdMob requires FireBase. But FireBase does not support React Native out of box. I used a wrapper called React-Native-Firebase to make it work. https://rnfirebase.io/
https://firebase.google.com/
https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-admob/

**FB Ads: Supported**
I haven’t verified it myself. But it seems to be well documented. (And React Native being related to Facebook, I’d be surprised if it weren’t supported.) https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fbads

**Flurry: NOT supported**
Flurry Analytics supports React Native but Flurry Ads do not. Below is message from their support team when I asked them about this.
"Thank you for contacting Flurry Technical Support. We offer a React Native wrapper, however it does not currently support ads, only analytics. You can read more about it here: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/react-native/ "

**MoPub: Not really**
I’ve found two React Native wrappers. One is old and no longer updated. (The authors seem to be actively monitoring the discussions and replying to queries. But they are no longer providing tech support.) And the other is very new and doesn’t seem to have enough documentation or evidence that it actually works.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mopub
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mopub-sdk